# Android: Associate an AlertDialog with a specific view

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have tabs that when tapped will show a view for each tab. Is it possible to create an AlertDialog that is specific to a particular view and only shows when the view is shown? So if the user taps on one tab, they would see an AlertDialog but if they tap on a different tab, the AlertDialog will not show. I don't believe its possible because I believe an AlertDialog is global within the app and when shown comes to the foreground making it impossible to tap on anything else until the dialog is dismissed. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. You may try to switch to Fragments and FragmentDialog as that would allow you to 'bind' dialog to a fragment, and each fragment can sit on separate 'tab' of your app (yet, you'd need to rework your app anyway). If you want to use 'traiditional' dialog, then you have to add a logic yourself, and not show it if different than expected tab is visible.